# How to index HDFS pdf files in Solr?

Tags: hadoop, indexing, solr, hdfs

> hadoop jar jobjar/hadoop/hadoop-lws-job-1.2.0-0-0.jar
>   com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.IngestJob -Dlww.commit.on.close=true
>   -DcsvFieldMapping=0=id,1=text -cls com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.CSVIngestMapper -c hdp1 -i
>   /user/solr/data/csv/mydata.csv -of
>   com.lucidworks.hadoop.io.LWMapRedOutputFormat -s
>   http://localhost:8983/solr

I've tried using code above in the command to execute PDF files, but I get undesired output !

`com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.CSVIngestMapper` is used for exclusive CSV files, so is there anything similar to this for "PDF files"?
Looking forward for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DirectoryIngestMapper:

```
hadoop jar jobjar/hadoop/hadoop-lws-job-1.2.0-0-0.jar 
com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.IngestJob -Dlww.commit.on.close=true    
com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.DirectoryIngestMapper -c hdp1 -i 
/user/solr/data/pdf/*.pdf -of com.lucidworks.hadoop.io.LWMapRedOutputFormat -s 
http://localhost:8983/solr
```

Assuming that `/user/solr/data/pdf/*.pdf` is where your pdfs are.